# My Quest Giver Just Became a Zombie?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, skyrim-dragonborn

I am playing Skyrim Dragonborn and I got a quest from Glover Mallory (who happens to be Delvin's brother) to find the `Ancient Nord Pickaxe`. Last known location was with `Crescius Caerellius`. Tracked this guy down, convinced Crescius to hand over the pickaxe before starting the mission.

Now when I try to return it, this is what I see. This guy is praying or proselytizing to an Altar?
[image]

The person Glover Mallory is like a zombie. WTF gives? How do I complete this quest?

A word no spoilers please. I still do not know WTF is happening. Thanks.

Comment: Y'know, you're one of the last people I'd have expected to be behind me in anything Skyrim. Just started the DLCs last month, and I'm already done with the primary Dragonborn story. Still got some work to do in Dawnguard and some more houses to build for Hearthfire.

Comment: 'proselytizing' ! Say what a sizing ?

Comment: @desaivv Ah, didn't realize you were on the PC for some reason. Only reason I took this long to get around to it myself was 'cause I'd been playing on the PS3 - didn't have an Xbox until Christmas.

Comment: @desaivv I wouldn't say anything was lost in translation. Even if so, the screenshot helps. I think Terry was primarily just pointing out that the word is not one often used in conversation, so not as many people might be familiar with it. According to [Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/proselytizing) though, the word (while being *on-topic*) is probably just a bit outside of its proper usage.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just continue about your business for now. You will eventually get (if you have not already) a quest that involves you breaking the enchantment that has taken over Mallory and others. When that's done, you should be able to wrap up his side-quest.

*Note: I could go into more detail, and provide Wikia links, but that would be violating your request for avoiding spoilers.*

Comment: @desaivv Given that this is a Bethesda game, I don't blame you.